# Running Linux executables on NTFS partition marked with execute permission

Tags: ntfs, executable

I have just installed Ubuntu 12.04, I used `ntfs-config` to auto-mount the NTFS partition on boot and I checked that the `fstab` file is configured as usual with ntfs-3g and with write and execute permissions.

I also verified that all files are listed with `rwx` to everybody.

The problem is that whenever I try to run Linux executable files (Linux binary) located on the NTFS partition, it says: `no such file or directory`.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be that I am using a 32 bit version on 64 bit system.

Comment: Perhaps you can accept your answer, or remove the question, to stop this question showing up on the unanswered tab...?

Comment: Ah, ok - I didn't know about that.  Thanks.